# Which keypath need to send APN message from Vapor + Heroku?

Tags: heroku, apple-push-notifications, vapor

Using [vapor-apns](https://github.com/matthijs2704/vapor-apns). Want to do authentication. Attached `APNsAuthKey_AQ34EHZCDQ.p8` file to `Vapor` project, to `frozen-sea-***`. But I do not know the key path. What you use?

```
let options = try! Options(topic: "<your bundle identifier>", teamId: "<your team identifier>", keyId: "<your key id>", keyPath: "/path/to/your/APNSAuthKey.p8")
let vaporAPNS = try VaporAPNS(options: options)
```

Found here a [string](https://github.com/matthijs2704/vapor-apns/issues/32), but it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reference a file path relative to your Vapor application, use `drop.workDir` to get the absolute path to your application's directory.

```
let options = try Options(
  topic: "<your bundle identifier>",
  teamId: "<your team identifier>",
  keyId: "<your key id>",
  keyPath: drop.workDir + "/Secrets/APNSAuthKey.p8"
)
let vaporAPNS = try VaporAPNS(options: options)
```